# @synchronization but only once

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a situation where multiple network calls run at the same time may run into the same error at the same time. When the error happens i want the network call to execute a separate request for different auth data.

What i am running into is that all network calls will run into the same error and the code for the auth data request will execute four times. I only want it to run once.

So i created this method which gets triggered by a NSNotification.

```
static NSNumber *skipRefresh; 
@synchronized(skipRefresh) {
  if (!skipRefresh.boolValue) {
    skipRefresh = @(YES);
    [self refresh:^{
      //Do stuff
      skipRefresh = @(NO);
    } failure:^{
      //Do stuff
      skipRefresh = @(NO);
    }
  }
}
```

I am assuming this code will not work or at the very worst i will run into an eventual race condition.

How will i achieve what i am looking for where i run the code only once and not sequential?

Comment: Why on earth is skipRefresh an NSNumber* and not just a BOOL?

Comment: It is, because `@synchronized` expects an object. But Rohan misunderstood, how `@synchronized` works.

Comment: Do you use `NSURLSession`?

Answer (score 1):

You could put it in a `dispatch_once` block.

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
                dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
                  //Do stuff once here per app launch
                });
```

Comment: I do not think that this helps. He does not want to run auth one time per app run, but one time for queued requests.